# Why is my page reloaded after model.close()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following problems:

1- When my model is open and I click 'cancel' to close it, it reloads the page.

2- When I click 'OK', my 'DELETE'-request is not sent to the server (it doesn't receive anything) and the page is reloaded. I'm also not redirected to the page I'm meant to go to.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="suppr()" value="ok"/>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="annulSupp()" value="cancel" />
  </div>
```

**file js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var progress = angular.module('demret.progress', ['ui.bootstrap.modal']);


    progress.directive('progressDem', function() {
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            templateUrl : "progress/progress.html",
            controller : [ '$scope', '$http', 'Demande', '$window', '$modal', function($scope, $http, Demande, $window, $modal) {
                // TODO

                $scope.supprimerDemande = function() {

                    var urlSetDem = cfg.urlDDRRest + 'demande/' + Demande.get().id;
                    var config = {
                        method : 'DELETE',
                        url : urlSetDem,
                        jsonExpected : true
                    };
                    $http(config).then(function(http) {
                        $window.location.href = cfg.urlPortail;
                    })['catch'](function(http) {
                        $scope.errT= 'Une erreur technique'; 
                    })['finally'](function() {
                    });
                }

                // ==========================================
                // open fenetre modal 
                // ==========================================
                $scope.modalSuppressionDem = function(size) {
                    // déclaration de la fenetre
                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        animation : true,
                        templateUrl : 'progress/suppression-modal.html',
                        controller : 'ModalSuppressionDem',
                        size : size,
                        backdrop : 'static',
                        resolve : {
                            functionSupp : function() {
                                return $scope.supprimerDemande;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                        // close
                    });
                };

            } ]
        }
    });


    // Controleur de la fenetre modale 
    progress.controller('ModalSuppressionDem', [ '$scope', '$modalInstance', 'functionSupp', function($scope, $modalInstance, functionSupp) {
        $scope.suppr = function() {
            functionSupp();
            $modalInstance.close();
        };
        $scope.annulSupp = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };
    } ]);

})();
```

**config.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.cfg = {

        urlDDRRest : '/TOTO-rs/api/',
        urlPortail : '/TOTO/',

    };
})();
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This logic is a little strange, and I smell scope creep.. but why not use `data-dismiss="modal"` in the HTML instead of a close function ?

Comment: i m not expert in angular :(, give me a solution or example tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

replace

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="annulSupp()" value="cancel" />
```

with

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="annulSupp($event)" value="cancel" />
```

and  replace $scope.annulSupp() function with below code

```
$scope.annulSupp = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $modalInstance.close();
};
```

Comment: i m not expert in angularjs: where i add it? i must replace my code?

Comment: it's ok for cancel it s working, the solution for the second problem() OK button tks

Comment: i passe a reference for function  supprimerDemande, you can see it in  $scope.modalSuppressionDem  functionSupp : function() {
                                return $scope.supprimerDemande;
                            }

Comment: Why are you writing all the code inside Directive instead of Controller. It is better to write logic inside a Controller.

Comment: i use event.preventDefault(); for the second problem and it s resolved, tks